# MySQL Full-Text search query with MATCH return strange result order

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search

I need to query a table using the following query:

```sql
SELECT cards.name, MATCH(`cards.name`) AGAINST("Swiftfoot Boot") AS relevance
FROM cards
WHERE MATCH(`cards.name`) AGAINST("Swiftfoot Boot")
ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

Here is my [db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kY5q93xyNWR57AqBD5ukrk/3) with schema and records.

If you run the query you can see that the first result with the highest relevance is "Boot Nipper", but I expect to have "Swiftfoot Boots" (note the 's' at the end). Any idea why this strange order result and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Natural Language Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

> Every correct word in the collection and in the query is weighted according to its significance in the collection or query. Thus, a **word that is present in many documents has a lower weight**, because it has lower semantic value in this particular collection. Conversely, if the word is rare, it receives a higher weight. The weights of the words are combined to compute the relevance of the row. This technique works best with large collections.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kY5q93xyNWR57AqBD5ukrk/4)